# Jquery image gallery plugin with thumbnail functionality

Tags: jquery

I found **[cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html)** suitable to my need, but don't have a thumbnail.

There have a ready made plugin looks like an image below?

1. On the main image when we click go to the next image
2. Have thumbnails for other image

[image]

Comment: Can you be bit more clear, about what you exactly want?

Comment: @vishwanath like cycle plugin but have thumbnail for other images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many plugins out there, which might be providing this functionality.

I have used exposure image gallery for my needs.
Provides many of the options.

Demo 3 looks like same as your requirement :
http://exposure.blogocracy.org/demos/demo3.html?v=1.0

You can check out other examples here
http://exposureforjquery.wordpress.com/demo/

Home page :
http://exposureforjquery.wordpress.com/